swipeActions abnormal behaviour
I want the list in my app to be able to use swipe for each row. Normally I use swipeActions(edge:allowsFullSwipe:content) for this and everything worked. But this time I'm facing a situation where swipeActions doesn't work at all. It seems that the corresponding code  is just ignored. I am totally confused and would welcome any help or advice.
Below is a code snippet
struct MainView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack {
                VStack{
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        //... 

                        ForEach(paymentDataForView) { transaction in
                            TransactionCellView(transaction: transaction)
                                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false, content: {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        //some code
                                    }) 
                                    
                                    Button(action: {
                                        some code
                                    }) 
                                })
                                .onTapGesture {
                   //some code
                                }
                                .contextMenu {
                 //some code
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            .onWillAppear(initialisationAfterLaunch)
        }
    }
}


struct TransactionCellView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var transaction: PaymentActivity
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            if transaction.isFault {
                EmptyView()
                
            }  else {
                
                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.up.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(transaction.name)
                        .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}



I tried to simplify all the code, just to keep minimum to handle swipe action, but it still doesn't work.

Swipe actions don't work outside of a List-like thing. You need to roll your own.
